# Submit form using Bootstrap 4 AJAX submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using Bootstrap 4's js validation that they include:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated')
            }
            , false)
        })
    }, false)
}());
```

- Index.php has the `<form>` tags.
- Form.php has the PHPMailer call
- This section is in a validation.js file

How can I bind that with an AJAX submit call? I want to use the default JS Validation provided by Bootstrap 4 above but also make a call to AJAX to check the php validation and then submit.

I can't for the life of me find a mix combination for Bootstrap 4 + AJAX + PHP.

Comment: Assuming that you mean you want to also execute this code when an AJAX request completes successfully, put the logic in to a function and call it from both places.

Comment: That is correct @RoryMcCrossan, I have a file called form.php that had methods to check validation but I'm having trouble mixing in the following:

Form is in index.php
PHPMailer is in form.php

I want to make a call to AJAX to submit the form but also check form.php for the validation using Bootstrap 4's default validation as provided above.